# animate activity switching right to left while keeping the background image staionary

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want a right to left animation on change of activity as described in the image below. But I want to keep the background image fixed. the elements of the activities should move over it.

How can I achieve this. [image]

Comment: Use Fragments (s. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: Is there any reason why not using single activity with background and switch fragments with animation?

Comment: Is there any other solution. I have already coded a big part of my code without fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no other good solution other than using fragments view pager, or else remove all the items in activity 1 and place activity 2 items in activity 1 with animation , use view pager best option..

Answer (score 1):

One idea:

Set the activity2 background to transparent.

Do the activity switch

Edit "onCreate" method of activity2 to set the same background programmatically